# How to achieve corner gradient in android?

Tags: android, gradient

I need to have **corner gradient** for a button. i.e Light fills from the Bottom left corner upwards.

I tried this way:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#E60000"
    android:centerColor="#800000"
    android:endColor="#E60000"
    android:type="sweep" />
```

However It just fills the light from right to left. Could anybody help me out?

Answer (score 4):

Try to give 135 or 225 for angle value

`android:angle="135"` or `android:angle="225"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried same way.There is no any noticeable changes.

Comment: hımm do you apply any other effects rather than this gradient? and make sure using the correct file?

Comment: No.I don't apply any other effects and yes, I'm using correct file.

Comment: I found that discarding the centerColor and type attributes in the above XML and then setting the angle to 135 solves the problem.

Comment: I was sure there is something blocking it, glad you solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it programmatically:

```
yourView.background = GradientDrawable(
  Orientation.BL_TR,
  intArrayOf(Color.RED, Color.GREEN),
)
```